# TypeScript: Class that implements interfaces static methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am writing a node.js express app where I have a class Organizer that should implement the interface IUser.

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

interface IUser {
  Register(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void>;
  Login(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void>;
}

class Organizer implements IUser {
  public static async Register(req: Request, res: Response) {
    return res.json({ registered: true });
  }

  public static async Login(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    return res.json({ organizer: 'hallo' });
  }
}
```

Whats wrong about my code? I get the error message: `Class 'Organizer' incorrectly implements interface 'IUser'. Type 'Organizer' is missing the following properties from type 'IUser': Register, Login`

The Methods `Register` and `Login` should be private in order to use them later in the Express Router with `Organizer.Register`.

Comment: Interfaces are not intended for implementing as static members of classes. I'm certain that this is how they are designed in many languages. Interfaces are public contracts so all their members should be implemented as public instance members of classes.

Comment: If you have `class X implements Y`, the *instances* of `X` need to match `Y`, not the static `X` constructor itself.  If you need something like `static implements` it's not part of the language (request at [ms/TS#33892](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892)) but you could get similar behavior by just assigning the constructor to the type and seeing if there's an error; `satisfies` makes this easy-ish.  But if you only have static members you probably don't want a class anyway, why not just an object? See [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/mq9z2m) for various approaches. ...

Comment: ... if that fully addresses your question I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the replies. I no longer use static methods.
Then I will write this in my Router file.
`let organizer = new Organizer();
router.post('/register', organizer.Register);
router.post('/login', organizer.Login);`